# Cannot open database. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, networking, localdb

I'm trying to deploy my first ASP.NET app on IIS, but I'm facing an issue whenever I connect to database. Connecting to database works just fine running the app on visual studio.

I keep getting the following:

> SqlException: Cannot open database "RazorPagesMovieContext-ae4522b8-14f6-4dd9-9e71-fb8009d965ad" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.

My connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" 
     connectionString="Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=RazorPagesMovieContext-ae4522b8-14f6-4dd9-9e71-fb8009d965ad;Integrated Security=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Like stated in the article here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlexpress/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership I have tried #1 "Run IIS as our Windows user" and #2 "Use LocalDB Shared Instance" of the approaches without any luck so I've moved to trying NetworkService instead of ApplicationPoolIdentity which is where I'm facing the same error (using `ApplicationPoolIdentity` it fails with

> Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL.NET v4.5'") just under different user.

In my SQL Server Management Studio I've created a new user with "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" name and made sure I gave "db owner" permission for the database and ticked all Server Roles. Most of the answers point out to giving permissions, but that still does not address this for me.

Any insights would be appreciated

Comment: Where are you deploying the ASP.NET application to?

Comment: **Using system account is very risky, especially with elevated privledges.** I strongly suggest creating a new SQL Server user account used solely for your application and use the connection string blow (filling in variables indicated with `{ ... }`) to connect.

Comment: I'm deploying it to a folder and then use IIS Manager to have the site running. Security is not my concern at this point, but I do have a user account "IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5" which still has the same login failure. Could you give an example what do you mean by "use the connection string blow (filling in variables indicated with { ... }) to connect"? I'm not sure I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your **ConnectionString**, you haven't any  user content CS  for Login Database.

> First you must add user for database your  then set your connectionString

**Two Options**

1. Create new user on your database then this user set access for **RazorPagesMovieContext-ae4522b8-14f6-4dd9-9e71-fb8009d965ad** [Create User](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHLNR_8.1.4/com.ibm.pm.doc/install/sql_config_agent_grant_permission_sqlserver.html)
2. Enable **sa** user, by default disabled **sa** user, [Enable Sa user](https://sudeeptaganguly.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/how-to-enable-sa-account-in-sql-server/)

**Finally Change connection string**

if you use **option 2**

```
Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=RazorPagesMovieContext-ae4522b8-14f6-4dd9-9e71-fb8009d965ad; user=sa; password=yourPassword
```

**For enable **

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the above link is useful, `Run IIS as our Windows user` or `Use LocalDB shared instance` is an approach to the issue.
I am here just to discuss the approach provided in the documentation. In solution1, firstly we should ensure that the VS is running properly because we should ensure the Database instance also is running properly. Then change the application pool identity to the Windows account running the Visual Studio.
[image]
In solution2, since Visual Studio2017  has updated the name of the local database instance, we should change the command accordingly.

```
sqllocaldb share instance mssqllocaldb IIS_DB
```

Subsequently, apply it to the connection string.

```
Data Source=(localdb)\.\IIS_DB;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=True
```

Here is a detailed description of this issue.
https://codemegeek.com/2018/05/13/configure-iis-to-us-localdb/
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.